# implement third-party framework swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoapods

How could I install a third party framework (in my case [PhoneNumberKit](https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit)) in my project? I tried CocoaPods and Carthage but they both don't work.

I use Xcode 7 and Swift 2.2

**Edit**

Is there a way to install a framework **without** tools like cocoapods or carthage?

Comment: *"... but they both don't work"* is a useless problem description.

Comment: @MartinR Why? There is a valid answer: "You did something wrong."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, i think it work!

```
use_frameworks!

target 'nameOfYourProject' do

    platform :ios, '9.0'

    pod 'PhoneNumberKit', :git => 'https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit.git'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

download the git hub source and added it to your project.create bridging header to include objective-c header file to import into your swift project.

import the header files of that objective-c library on that header file and you can use it.

this is the only way to use framework libraries without using pod.

Thanks